# Is it possible to subtract days, months or years from current date in swift

Tags: swift, date, time, swiftui

Hello I want to subtract days, months or a year from my current date.
I can use this code to create a date which is one week away from the current date.

```
let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(86400*7))
```

Is it possible to create a date which is one week in the past from the current date?

Comment: When you say "...I want to remove days, months or a year from my current date" you mean you want to subtract a certain number of days, months, or years from a date? Or do you mean you want a Date that does not include a month (or year) value? Tarun's answer tells you how to subtract calendar units from a Date. The second thing doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean the first thing. Remove is maybe a bad description for it. I will change it into subtract.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `Calendar` to do these calculations instead of hard coding `86400` for a day.

```
if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date()) {
   // Use this date
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

Function to add or subtract day, month, year from current date.

```
func addOrSubtractDay(day:Int)->Date{
  return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: Date())!
}

func addOrSubtractMonth(month:Int)->Date{
  return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: month, to: Date())!
}

func addOrSubtractYear(year:Int)->Date{
  return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: year, to: Date())!
}
```

Now calling the function

```
//Subtracting
var daySubtractedDate = addOrSubtractDay(-7)
var monthSubtractedDate = addOrSubtractMonth(-7)
var yearSubtractedDate = addOrSubtractYear(-7)

//Adding
var dayAddedDate = addOrSubtractDay(7)
var monthAddedDate = addOrSubtractMonth(7)
var yearAddedDate = addOrSubtractYear(7)
```

- To Add date pass prospective  value
- To Subtract pass negative
  value

Answer (score 3):

Add below extension:

```
extension Date {
    func get(_ components: Calendar.Component..., calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> DateComponents {
        return calendar.dateComponents(Set(components), from: self)
    }

    func get(_ component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Int {
        return calendar.component(component, from: self)
    }
}
```

Use extension as below:

```
let date = Date()

let components = date.get(.day, .month, .year)
if let day = components.day, let month = components.month, let year = components.year {
    print("day: \(day), month: \(month), year: \(year)")
}
```

For getting last week date exact from today

```
let lastWeekDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())!
```

Comment: The way with the extension is very interesting. :)

Comment: Extensions make your programing easy, because with the help of extension you can reduce your code and its complexity.

Comment: Why not have your get function take a Set of Calendar.Component values rather than using variadic arguments? That's how developers are used to seeing components listed.